# Can't see LOCAL java applets in my browser

Tags: 12.10, firefox, java, applet

So I setup the Java plugin for Firefox, and can see applets that are not stored locally. But whenever I try to run applets that are stored on my machine I get an "Application Blocked by Security Settings: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running." Why is this and how do I fix it? I get the feeling that it's ubuntu permissions, not firefox permissions... but I'm not sure.

I am running 12.10 Desktop with Gnome3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running openJDK, then search for IcedTea Web Control Panel, and click on it.

[image]

Once the window opens check the security settings.  When done click OK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. All I needed to do was remove the official plugin from oracle and use the iced tea one instead.